# New to VB. My code generates the error: "expecting End With". How do the with-end with statements work?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub RowRangeMove()
    Sheets.Add().Name = "CopySheet"
    With Sheets("BigDataSet - Copy")
        .Range("A65000", .Range("A13000").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("A1")
    With Sheets("BigDataSet - Copy")
        .Range("B65000", .Range("B13000").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("B1")
    With Sheets("BigDataSet - Copy")
        .Range("C65000", .Range("C13000").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("C1")
    With Sheets("BigDataSet - Copy")
        .Range("D65000", .Range("D13000").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("D1")
    With Sheets("BigDataSet - Copy")
        .Range("E65000", .Range("E13000").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("E1")
    With Sheets("BigDataSet - Copy")
        .Range("F65000", .Range("F13000").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("F1")
    With Sheets("BigDataSet - Copy")
        .Range("G65000", .Range("G13000").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("G1")
    With Sheets("BigDataSet - Copy")
        .Range("H65000", .Range("H13000").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("H1")
    With Sheets("BigDataSet - Copy")
        .Range("I65000", .Range("I13000").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("I1")
    With Sheets("BigDataSet - Copy")
        .Range("J65000", .Range("J13000").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("J1")
    End With
    .
    .
    [iterate several times]
    .
    .
    Sheets.Add().Name = "CopySheet7"
    With Sheets("BigDataSet - Copy")
        .Range("A455006", .Range("A502750").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("A1")
    With Sheets("BigDataSet - Copy")
        .Range("B455006", .Range("B502750").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("B1")
    With Sheets("BigDataSet - Copy")
        .Range("C455006", .Range("C502750").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("C1")
    With Sheets("BigDataSet - Copy")
        .Range("D455006", .Range("D502750").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("D1")
    With Sheets("BigDataSet - Copy")
        .Range("E455006", .Range("E502750").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("E1")
    With Sheets("BigDataSet - Copy")
        .Range("F455006", .Range("F502750").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("F1")
    With Sheets("BigDataSet - Copy")
        .Range("G455006", .Range("G502750").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("G1")
    With Sheets("BigDataSet - Copy")
        .Range("H455006", .Range("H502750").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("H1")
    With Sheets("BigDataSet - Copy")
        .Range("I455006", .Range("I502750").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("I1")
    With Sheets("BigDataSet - Copy")
        .Range("J455006", .Range("J502750").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("J1")
    End With


End Sub
```

When I try to run this, I get an error saying "expecting End With". The goal of the script is to copy ranges of rows and put them into new separate sheets (that I can then put into separate files that will read in Excel 2003 without exceeding the max number of rows). Should there be one or more additional End With statements somewhere in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only should there be at least one End With, there shouldn't be so many With statements.

```
Sub RowRangeMove()
    Sheets.Add().Name = "CopySheet"
    With Sheets("BigDataSet - Copy")
        .Range("A65000", .Range("A13000").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("A1")
        .Range("B65000", .Range("B13000").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("B1")
        .Range("C65000", .Range("C13000").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("C1")
        .Range("D65000", .Range("D13000").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("D1")
        .Range("E65000", .Range("E13000").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("E1")
        .Range("F65000", .Range("F13000").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("F1")
        .Range("G65000", .Range("G13000").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("G1")
        .Range("H65000", .Range("H13000").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("H1")
        .Range("I65000", .Range("I13000").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("I1")
        .Range("J65000", .Range("J13000").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("J1")
    End With

End Sub
```

would be the correct syntax.

The With statement is simply a way to shorten up your lines of code.  The With statement is a way of saying "I'm going to perform a bunch of actions on a specific object" and shorten up the individual lines of code.

Example:

Without the With statement, the code above would look like this:

```
Sub RowRangeMove()
    Sheets.Add().Name = "CopySheet"
        Sheets("BigDataSet - Copy").Range("A65000", .Range("A13000").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("A1")
        Sheets("BigDataSet - Copy").Range("B65000", .Range("B13000").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("B1")
        Sheets("BigDataSet - Copy").Range("C65000", .Range("C13000").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("C1")
        Sheets("BigDataSet - Copy").Range("D65000", .Range("D13000").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("D1")
        Sheets("BigDataSet - Copy").Range("E65000", .Range("E13000").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("E1")
        Sheets("BigDataSet - Copy").Range("F65000", .Range("F13000").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("F1")
        Sheets("BigDataSet - Copy").Range("G65000", .Range("G13000").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("G1")
        Sheets("BigDataSet - Copy").Range("H65000", .Range("H13000").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("H1")
        Sheets("BigDataSet - Copy").Range("I65000", .Range("I13000").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("I1")
        Sheets("BigDataSet - Copy").Range("J65000", .Range("J13000").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("J1")
End Sub
```

In shorter terms, the With statement allows you to start out individual lines of code with a dot, and inside that with statement, the compiler will assume you mean the thing declared in your with statement.

So

```
With Answerer
  ' Inside this with block, any line beginning with "." , 
  ' the compiler will assume you mean "Answerer.".   
  ' Therefore ".FirstName" is the same as "Answerer.FirstName"
  .FirstName = "David"
  .LastName = "Stratton"
End With
```

is equivalient to

```
Answerer.FirstName = "David"
Amswerer.LastName = "Stratton"
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to repeat the With part so many times.

```
With Sheets("BigDataSet - Copy")
  .Range("A65000", .Range("A13000").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("A1")
  .Range("B65000", .Range("B13000").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("B1")
  .Range("C65000", .Range("C13000").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("C1")
  ' Etc
End With
```

See the MSDN documentation for the "With" keyword:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
With Sheets("BigDataSet - Copy") 
    .Range("A455006", .Range("A502750").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("A1") 
    .Range("B455006", .Range("B502750").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("B1") 

    .Range("C455006", .Range("C502750").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("C1") 
    .Range("D455006", .Range("D502750").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("D1") 
    .Range("E455006", .Range("E502750").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("E1") 

    .Range("F455006", .Range("F502750").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("F1") 
    .Range("G455006", .Range("G502750").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("G1") 
    .Range("H455006", .Range("H502750").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("H1") 
    .Range("I455006", .Range("I502750").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("I1") 
    .Range("J455006", .Range("J502750").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Range("J1") 
End With
```

You only need one (Begin) `With` ([msdn reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)) . That's the whole point of that block, to let you not include the parent object each time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `With-End With` blocks at all. It looks like your first `With` block is taking some part of A13000:J65000 and copying it to a new worksheet, then taking some part of A455006:J502750 and pasting it onto a second new worksheet. Your code can be refactored as follows:

```
Sub RowRangeMove()

  Dim wkshts As Excel.Sheets
  Dim targetSheet As Excel.Worksheet
  Dim sourceSheet As Excel.Worksheet

  Set wkshts = Excel.Worksheets

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  ' create new sheet
  Set targetSheet = Excel.Worksheets.Add
  targetSheet.name = "CopySheet"

  ' copy from source to first target
  Set sourceSheet = Excel.Worksheets("BigDataSet - Copy")
  sourceSheet.Range(sourceSheet.Cells(13000, 1).End(xlUp), _
                    sourceSheet.Cells(65000, 10)).Copy targetSheet.Range("A1")

  ' create second new sheet
  Set targetSheet = Excel.Worksheets.Add
  targetSheet.name = "CopySheet7"

  ' copy from source to second target
  sourceSheet.Range(sourceSheet.Cells(455006, 1), _
                    sourceSheet.Cells(502750, 10).End(xlUp)).Copy targetSheet.Range("A1")

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```